# Trying to display key/value pairs in react component using map?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I have data returned from the backend which I wanted to display in react component with the below approach it is only printing the values, how do I print both keys and values in the DOM?

index.js

```js
{Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
  <Card>
      <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              <p>{data[key]}</p>
              <p>{data[value]}</p>
          </Typography>
      </CardContent>
  </Card>
))}
```

data sample

```js
{ 
  'User': ': Admin',
  'Location': ': New York, NY',
  'Company Name': ': Millenium'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `key` instead of `data[key]` and `value` instead of `data[value]`. Also, be sure to [provide a unique `key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) on each `map`ped item in your list.

```js
{Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
  <Card key={key}>
    <CardContent>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
        <p>{key}</p>
        <p>{value}</p>
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
  </Card>
))}
```